# Can you send data back to react app during a redirect

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, express

I apologize if this is a duplicate but I can't seem to find an exact answer. I'm either searching wrong or it's not possible.
The current flow for my site is for a user to login, be authenticated and then redirected to another route. At this route several components would need to load (right now I have it setup via ajax requests) but I'd like to already have this done.

When I redirect I've already looked up all the user info I need and don't like the idea of making a seperate db request when it's already been done. Is it possible to send data along with res.redirect() that can be read by react before components mount?

So, for example if the user presses login I make a post request to the server. The server then handles the login, creates a session, and in doing so has already looked them up in the database.

After they are redirected the landing page displays their name. What I am currently doing calling another ajax request just after the component on the landing page mounts. However what I'd like to do is send the name along with the redirect so I don't have to touch the db with a separate call.

UPDATE:
please note i'm using react, not a view template

Comment: I Didnt get that  "when I redirect i hv already look up the use data" is it in the redirected route you are fetchung the user? And then rendering the view? If it so then you can send the usedata to the view with a `,` seperator in the render method of node.js

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might want to use a plugin that will persist the state even after redirect then "rehydrates" your store with the persisted state. You can check:

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

With the limited clarity I got from 
Your question is not clear. Response.redirect is server side call, better call to an end point on login authentication call back which returns the data required for your react views to load after login. Once you have data you can load your views.